# tous les … ne sont pas

Tags: expressions, négation

Bonjour,

J'entends (et lis) souvent des phrases construites comme suit :

> Tous les chiens ne sont pas dangereux

Dans cet exemple on veut dire que les chiens ne sont pas tous dangereux. Mais au vu de la syntaxe, j'ai plus l'impression que ça veut dire qu'aucun chien n'est dangereux. Est-ce un abus de langage ou la construction est-elle correcte ?

Merci

Comment: See also http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19891/not-all-of-them-are-partial-negation-versus-all-of-them-are-not-complet/19896#19896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une question similaire a été posée récemment et elle avait de bonnes réponses :

[Expressing the negation of a statement that uses quantifiers](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24839/expressing-the-negation-of-a-statement-that-uses-quantifiers)

En résumé, la construction est correcte. Syntactiquement parlant, "tous les chiens ne sont pas dangereux" est ambigu et *pourrait* vouloir dire qu'aucun chien n'est dangereux, mais en pratique l'usage fait que la signification est clairement "les chiens ne sont pas tous dangereux", et quelqu'un qui voudrait dire autre chose dirait "aucun chien n'est dangereux", ou bien "tous les chiens sont inoffensifs", ou une autre construction qui évite l'ambigüité.